# Curves of functions

Tags: functions

Let $ f(x) = x-\sqrt{|x^2-4|} $ and $ g(x) = x+\sqrt{|x^2-4|} $

How can we draw the curve of $ f(x) $ knowing the curve of $ g(x) $ ?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f(x)+g(x)=2x$.  One approach is to plot $g(x)$ and $2x$ on the same set of axes.  Then the graph of $f(x)$ is the distance between them.  Another is to plot $-g(x)$ and add $2x$ to it.

Comment: And how do we interpret this distance between them geometrically ?

Comment: @Guru:  I am not sure I understand the question.  For a given $x$ you find the vertical distance between $g(x)$ and $2x$, then plot that to get $f(x)$.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Here is the graph of the two functions : http://photobase.ro/di-DXIU.png 
So where is the vertical distance that you're talking about. Can you clarify it to me please :)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I explain what Ross means:

look at $x_1, 2x_1-g_1=f_1x_1$,the distance is $ 2x_1-g_1$, but you must be very careful when $2x<g(x)$, the "-" should be "+" two distance, look at $x_2, |g_2x_2|=|f_2(2x_2)|$. I hope it will help you to understand.